# Chrome extension: How to change html of the page?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome

I'm using the following script within a Chrome extension I made. It replaces "old text" with "new text" of all pages.

> document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new
>   RegExp("old text", "g"), "new text");

So far, so good. But want to know how to find/replace the (java)scripts, meta tags and css files in within the  tags of the page in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stuff you are looking for resides in document.head.